# monoalphabetic ciper decryption?

Tags: java, encryption, jcreator

Can anybody see what i'm doing wrong here? I have an algorithm that encrypts a string by moving it 14 spaces along an array but when i try and decrypt it some of the letters are repeated for example
when encrypted: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  == opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn
when decrypted: opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn  == abcdefghijklklabcdefghijkl

```
char[] plaintext = input.toCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i<plaintext.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j<26; j++) {
        if(j>=14 && plaintext[i]==alphabet[j]) {
            plaintext[i] = alphabet[j-14];
            break;
        }

        else if(plaintext[i] == alphabet[j] && j<14 ) {
            plaintext[i] = alphabet [j+14] ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're trying is almost, just almost a Rot13, and that's not a form of encryption. Anyone with half a minute of free time will be able to reverse engineer it.

Comment: Yes, rot13 is a form of encryption. It's not a *strong* form of encryption, being a symmetric rotation (trivial substitution cipher).

Comment: Its an assignment, it's just what i was told to do.

Comment: @d99 maybe you could explain your logic here? It seems unnecessarily complicated to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resides in the fact that the operation you apply is not the same when the character is `>= 14` or `< 14`, and it is also wrong since it may go over bounds.

What you do is:

- `18 (>= 14) -> 18 - 14 = 4` but `18 + 14 = 32 = 26+6` and `6 != 4`
- `13 (<14) -> 13 + 14 = 27` which is out of bounds.

The approach is not correct, you should make the value wrap over the alphabet array and this can be done easily with the [mod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `%` operator:

```
newIndex = (oldIndex+shift) % alphabetLength
```

Without using the proper tools every a simple task becomes error prone and difficult to maintain. You could also do it without modulo but calculations should be correct, adding and subtracting `14` to the alphabet index surely doesn't create a valid mapping.

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to both java and encryption. How would this be implemented exactly in my case?

Comment: Since it's an assignment I guess you should try to solve it on your own, what I wrote is enough for you to understand your specific case. This assignment has nothing to do with encryption though, it is just programming.

Comment: I've been working on it for 4 days so far and its due tomorrow morning but i'll give it a shot, thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Take a look at similar question to understand how modulo works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964771/help-trying-to-understand-modulo-operation-in-circular-array http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=53

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at it but I don't think i'm gonna have time to get my head around it before tomorrow. Thanks for all your help, I've accepted your answer.

Comment: It's rather simple, the value to which you are mapping any character (which is the `currentIndex + 14`) must wrap around the array of characters. This is what modulo allows you to do easily.